# Delimit Cells in Excel with Click-and-Drag Formula

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have the following in Cell B1:

```
AB,1,CD,3,EFG,3,
```

I have a formula that splits the cell up by delimiter `,` and allows me to click and drag this horizontally to as many cells as I'd like.

The formula that allows me to click and drag, in cell C1, is the following:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($B1,",",REPT(" ",LEN($B1))),(COLUMNS($C1:C1)-1)*LEN($B1)+1,LEN($B1)))
```

A problem that I'm running into now is that I essentially have two different delimters in Cell B6.  Expected output would be the same as what's stated in Cells C1:K1, except I need an updated formula that will split by `(` and `)`

[image]

An excel formula solution is needed -- most likely just tweaking my current formula I've provided above. No macro solutions, please.

Comment: Does the updated formula has to work for () **and** , as delimiter?

Comment: Indeed, easiest would be to tweak your current formula: instead of `($B1,","` use `SUBSTITUTE($B6,"(",")"),")"`. So, we just turn all "(" into ")" and we have 1 delimiter left. New formula: `TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B6,"(",")"),")",REPT(" ",LEN($B6))),(COLUMNS($C6:C6)-1)*LEN($B6)+1,LEN($B6)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a formula for both cases, you can use this:

```
=LET(fixedBracket1,SUBSTITUTE($B1,"(",","),
fixedBracket2,SUBSTITUTE(fixedBracket1,")",","),
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(fixedBracket2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(fixedBracket2))),(COLUMNS($C1:C1)-1)*LEN(fixedBracket2)+1,LEN(fixedBracket2))))
```

It first replaces all (-Brackets with a comma, then all )-Brackets.

If you are on the Insider channel you could use [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7)

Comment: What's the Insider channel @Ike?

Comment: https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/windows

Comment: Is it just for windows? @Ike

Comment: if you go to the page, you can see a Mac tab as well ...

Comment: if I wanted to transpose this array now and list the ```AB,1,CD,3,EFG,3,``` for each cell within the transposed range, how would I do that?  This might need to be a separate question submission. @Ike

Comment: A nuance would be I'd like the transposed letters and numbers in their own respective columns, too.  This probably should just be a new question. @Ike

Comment: Yes - this should be a new question